# Is there an equivalent to /played?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I want to know how long I've spent playing Guild Wars 2 so far, in other games you can type /played and it will give you a break down of how long you've been playing so far on that character - some other games show this on a summary screen for each character so you can keep track.

Is there an equivalent for this in Guild Wars 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is!

Simply type **/age** to see your time played on that specific character (in hours), as well as across *all* characters.

[image]

Comment: Joke's on you! I already answered her in chat! >:D

Comment: oh no, I'm going to end up with 187 hours by next week at this rate :o